# Black Border / Outline Around Input Field With TailwindCSS and Flowbite Component in a React Project

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

- I have tried changing the flow bite TextInput component styles manually.

```
<TextInput name="firstname" id="firstname" className="focus:border-none focus:border-transparent focus:ring-0" shadow={true} placeholder="Firstname" />
```

- I have also searched through the developer tools and have found nothing that could be giving it a black border or ring.

Browser i'm using is opera

i've been head scratching this for a hour or so any help is appreciated

[Form Picture Active and UnActive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGlie.png)[Form Picture Active and UnActive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPYog.png)

Thank You everyone.

Comment: style ="border:2px black;"   does it allow inline CSS ?  Granted this would normally work but styling textboxes it might not.  Also maybe you like TailwindCSS but you might look into Bootstrap as well, its pretty good.

Comment: @easleyfixed Hey Thank you man, your suggestion for an inline style worked. Im going to mess around and see if i can include it in the tailwind main css file and see if i can globally affect the inputs with a style of outline: 0. I appreciate you! I have used bootstrap for years. I just made the switch from bootstrap to tailwind when i started using react more often. I find it easier and just as useful as bootstrap components when its combined with a component library like flowbite or headless ui

Comment: I will go ahead and mark this up in an Answer if you would mark is as accepted I would appreciate that.  Ahh thanks for the info about tailwind with react as some day I might have to convert what Im doing into that so the heads up is nice.

Comment: @easleyfixed Hey i'm sorry about the late response! I will mark it as answered, you helped a lot i appreciate it alot

Comment: No worries trust me I know how it goes, not a problem at all.  I appreciate it quite a bit, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `style` command INLINE to style the element like this, just insert this into your `HTML` code between the`<textbox >`  tag:

```
style ="border:2px black;"
```